# Acces key violations in append query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run an append query, but I keep getting key violations, I think DelledningID is the culprit, but not sure how to fix this, as I shouldn't be touching that or ProjektID.

```
INSERT INTO ProjektDelledning ( ProjektID, DelledningID, SaneringsmetKode, DatoOprettet, DatoOpdateret )
SELECT ProjektDelledning.ProjektID, ProjektDelledning.DelledningID, NySaneringsData.SaneringsmetodeKode AS SaneringsmetKode, IIf([ProjektDelledning].[DatoOprettet] Is Null,Date$()+" "+Time$(),[ProjektDelledning].[DatoOprettet]) AS DatoOprettet, IIf([ProjektDelledning].[SaneringsmetKode] Is Null,Date$()+" "+Time$(),[ProjektDelledning].[DatoOpdateret]) AS DatoOpdateret
FROM NySaneringsData LEFT JOIN ProjektDelledning ON NySaneringsData.DelledningsID = ProjektDelledning.DelledningID
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT * FROM ProjektDelledning WHERE ProjektDelledning.SaneringsmetKode = NySaneringsData.SaneringsmetodeKode AND ProjektDelledning.DelledningID = NySaneringsData.DelledningsID))=False));
```

How do I got about fixing this? I tried removing Projekt ID and DelledningID from the query, but that gives a validations error instead.

[image: Key violation and tables]

Comment: You're trying to insert combinations of ProjektID and DelledningID that already exist. What does your table **ProjektDelledning** represent?

Comment: If by represent you mean what it contains, ProjectID (ProjektID) number which comes from a different table, a pipeID (DelledningID) from a different table, a repairnumber (SaneringmetKode) which needs to be appended with values based on the table NySaneringsData, the join being on the delledningID and it needs to update the date time on DatoOpdateret.

Comment: It is related to a projekt table. This pretty paint screendump shows how, I think :)
[TableRelationship](http://imgur.com/4FiM8zH)

Comment: For one thing, you could (and should) replace the expressions like `IIf([ProjektDelledning].[DatoOprettet] Is Null,Date$()+" "+Time$(),[ProjektDelledning].[DatoOprettet]) AS DatoOprettet` with: `Nz([ProjektDelledning].[DatoOprettet], Now()) As DatoOprettet`

Comment: I suspect that your database is not normalized. I have too less information as for what you're trying to achieve but you should reconsider your combined primary key in your destination table (ProjectDelledning). You should either add some sort of ID column and use that your primary key. Or add SaneringmetKode to your combined primary key. If you're gonna add some sort of ID column and use that as primary key, you could consider creating an unique index containing ProjektID, DelledningID and SaneringmetKode. Anyway, your current combined primary key is part of your problem.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much Rene. I can't really change anything in the database table structure of Projekt and ProjektDelledning, because they are used in an addon program for Microstation. 
Is there no way to just have the ProjektID and DelledningsID in the append query, without them actually doing anything? Just to avoid validation errors?

Comment: No. I'm wondering whether it's actually an update you're looking for as in update ProjektDelledning with the correct SaneringmetKode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching this incorrectly. You cannot insert new records into the ProjektDelledning without a "valid" project_id. You don't have a valid project_id and you cannot steal it from existing records because you would then create duplicate records and hit the validation error.

assuming your NySaneringsData has only unique delledningid,
try updating the ProjektDelledning table. something like.

```
update 
    ProjektDelledning INNER JOIN ProjektDelledning ON NySaneringsData.DelledningsID = ProjektDelledning.DelledningID
set
    ProjektDelledning.SaneringsmetKode =  NySaneringsData.SaneringsmetKode ,
    ProjektDelledning.DatoOprettet = nz(ProjektDelledning.DatoOprettet, now()),
    ProjektDelledning.DatoOpdateret = nz(ProjektDelledning.DatoOpdateret, now())
WHERE ( if any further conditions needed);
```

if NySaneringsData has duplicate delledningsid then you need to makesure which record you want to take over.

Comment: Thank you for the help Krish. NySaneringsData has the same DelledningID as ProjektDelledning, so is it still possible to add the records? The code you've shown, gives me a syntax error on the join.

Comment: I think you need to read more about rational-database designing. your db design tells us, to create new record in the "ProjektDelledning " you need to have a valid project_id and delledning_id. you are getting "NEW" delledning_id from NySaneringsData, where would you get a "NEW" project_id from? you cannot have duplicate records, so adding won't work. only update will work. @FoolzRailer

Comment: yes the inner join should be ProjektDelledning inner join NySaneringsData @FoolzRailer